# Determining which img src loads when using fallback attribute

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to determine which of the following (the fallback or the src link) actually gets rendered to the screen:

```
<a href="http://itemlink"><img fallback="http://link1.gif" src="http://link2.gif"></a>
```

I need a way of figuring out which of the images I would actually see on my screen (using PHP).

Note: This is the first time I've seen the fallback attribute and this is part of someone else's code (I've replaced the actual links for security reasons).

Comment: To answer your question, the image under the `src` attribute would be the one that is shown by default.

Comment: Right, but I need a way (preferably in PHP) to identify when the fallback image is being shown to a user.

Comment: Include that in the question!

Comment: fallback is not a standard image attribute reference http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/img#HTML_Attributes

Answer (score 1):

Rahter then using `fallback` you should use `onerror`.

```
<img src="http://link1.gif"
onerror='this.onerror = null; this.src="http://link2.gif"' />
```

This works also great crossbrowser.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I forgot to add that I cannot change this code, it's coming from another application.

Comment: @SuspiciousFish, as @Orangepill already mentioned `fallback` is not a valid HTML img tag attribute, where does it come from? are there maybe some errors that are thrown or some other events you can listen to in order to be notified?

Answer (score 0):

Update the onerror to

http://domain.com/track.php=failed_image_on_screen=link1.gif

The browser then should make a http request to the php script so you can catch and log